# Best practices for handling my own errors and openbrush's errors?

Tags: ink, astar, openbrush

- I am using ink! to implement the contract.
- I have implemented my own error, and the contract function has this own error as a return value.
- For example, suppose that function implements openbrush's Ownable.
- I implemented openbrush's Error implementation as follows.
- What would be the best way to implement it then?
- Referenced source code:https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/blob/main/contracts/src/traits/errors/psp37.rs

```
    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, scale::Encode, scale::Decode)]
    #[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
    pub enum MyError {
        MyError1,
        OwnableErrorCallerIsNotOwner,
        OwnableErrorNewOwnerIsZero,
    }
    impl From<OwnableError> for MyError {
        fn from(ownable: OwnableError) -> Self {
            match ownable {
                OwnableError::CallerIsNotOwner => MyError::OwnableErrorCallerIsNotOwner,
                OwnableError::NewOwnerIsZero => MyError::OwnableErrorNewOwnerIsZero,
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `pub fn function(&self) -> Result<(), MyError> {}` are you talking about something like this? [PSP37Error](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/blob/main/contracts/src/traits/errors/psp37.rs) and [PSP37Error Implementation](https://github.com/Supercolony-net/openbrush-contracts/blob/main/examples/psp37/lib.rs)

Comment: Sorry if my question is hard to understand. I'm a rust beginner. It seems inefficient to me to implement a From function to wrap all the errors of interest. So I would like to ask if there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to have an enum field that will encapsulate the Ownable error, and implement the From trait for it:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, scale::Encode, scale::Decode)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
pub enum MyError {
    OwnableError(OwnableError)
    MyError1,
}

impl From<OwnableError> for MyError {
    fn from(error: OwnableError) -> Self {
        MyError::OwnableError(error)
    }
}
```

example [here](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/wasm-showcase-dapps/blob/ad0f13f2287211a1d376096a4f7e941f55878a00/farming/logics/traits/master_chef/errors.rs#L10)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Ossun!  I think your way is better than mine.